# How to Upload .Net Website to Hosting for it to work?

Tags: c#, .net, hosting

To learn more about .Net I created a website but now I want to learn how to Host it, in PHP I would just upload the files to the host and check everything how do I do this with a .Net website?

I have 2 Databases, Controllers, and Views.

I done some research and people said to just upload the files from the bin folder which I tried but it did not work, also tried just tried uploading the DLL files with no success.

Also tried uploading all the files from the project folder but it did not work.

Found a tutorial which right click the project and publish it so I tried publishing it to a folder and then uploading that but that did not work to.

Comment: You can usually publish your website via ftp to your webhost.  I would check with your web host and see how they recommended publishing an asp.net web site

Answer (score 1):

To successfully publish and run your website on your host machine, the host machine must first have IIS (Microsoft's [Internet Information Server](https://www.iis.net/)) installed and running.

Once you have that in place there are several different approaches to deploy your website to the host. Here is a link to guidance from Microsoft's asp.net site in regards to ["Choosing the Right Approach to Web Deployment"](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/choosing-the-right-approach-to-web-deployment).

Specifically, for you to be able to go "right click -> Publish" from within Visual Studio the relevant approach is "Web Deploy Handler (Publishing)" and you can find detailed instructions for setting it up in ["Configuring a Web Server for Web Deploy Publishing (Web Deploy Handler)"](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler).

Answer (score 0):

You just upload the files.

But you msut be sure that IIS is configured th acctually watch for a .NET app in the folder it loads in.

For normal we apps you did the right:

> Also tried uploading all the files from the project folder but it did not work.

If it "just does not work" then it means .NET is just not there on that server or the folder you upload to is not configured to load a .NET project. Period. This is a fallback (technically you can upload less - the project file, i.e., is not needed), but it should work.